# CSS Grid question, icon not showing where I expect it to

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I am creating a small quiz application. It shows a question and several answers to choose from, pretty standard. Each of the potential answers is represented by text in a DIV. When a user selects an answer, I want to mark it as correct/incorrect by displaying an icon on the right side of the DIV. The DIV's width is dynamic, so I don't want to use "position" to place it. I figured it might make sense to simply turn the DIV into a display:grid, make two columns, have the text span both columns and place the icon in the second column (right aligned) which should keep it in the correct place.

https://jsfiddle.net/p5zjoxq6/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message">
This is a message that should span the cell and go under the icon
    </div>
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/2266EE/search" class="icon" alt=""><!-- This icon should appear on the right and float over the text -->
</div>

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
  width: 425px;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.message {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.icon {
  grid-column: 2;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the icon is showing up *under* the text, and taking up space which is making the DIV extra tall (height). I want the icon to be right aligned, over the text, and not take up extra space. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you considered position: absolute so it doesn't take up any space? You may want to increase the padding on the text to stop it looking too squished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AHaworth says, absolute positioning is the way to go.

```css
.container {
  width: 425px;
  background-color: salmon;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0.5em;
  width: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="message">
      This is a message that should span the cell and go under the icon but it also might be really long and so it would need to wrap
    </div>
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/2266EE/search" class="icon">
</div>
```